# Is it possible to write Visual Studio 2010 macros in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# for writing macros in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441944/c-for-writing-macros-in-visual-studio)

Is there a way to write Visual Studio 2010 macros in C#? If not, any idea when this will be possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441944/c-for-writing-macros-in-visual-studio