# Add DLL reference to visual studio macros

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, visual-studio-macros

I need to create a lot of macros in visual studio the probelem is I do not know visual basic that good.

What I have been doing so far is:

> Create the algorithm "Code" I plan to use on C# on a console
>   application. I complile it then decomplite it with [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) into
>   visual basic.
>
> When I decompile the code I lose the comments plus sometimes I have to
>   refer back to the code and it becomes hard to manage.

I am tired of compiling and decompiling plus I have to make a few twick every now and then. I will like to create a service or library that I could reference somewhere through:

[image]

**When I right click on reference and select add reference there is no way of selecting my own custom dll**.  Maybe there is a way of referencing the dll through code.

**What I been trying to do is trying to register the dll so that my dll would appear in:**
[image]

If I manage to register the dll it will be easier to supply my macros to other people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer might be here...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsx/thread/7b5d4c41-3a05-4a82-9a7d-aa6266fdbd25

....copy your assembly into

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

(change the Visual Studio version number in the path as appropriate)

Related links:

- [C# for writing macros in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441944/c-sharp-for-writing-macros-in-visual-studio)